# "shell not found" error on Gitlab pipeline attempting to run Microsoft Playwright tests

Tags: docker, gitlab, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-typescript

I am running into an issue running Microsoft Playwright on Gitlab.
When I kick off the test, I get the **shell not found** error after the image is pulled.

YML file

```
stages:
   - test

tests:
  rules:
      - when: manual
  stage: test
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.41.1-jammy
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npx playwright test
  artifacts:
    paths:  
      - playwright-report
      - test-results
      - results.xml/
    when: always
    expire_in: 120 days  
    reports:
        junit: results.xml
```

Error highlighted below

[image]

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: can you share your `config.toml` file if you are using your own gitlab runner ?

Comment: @EnergY
  
  [[runners]]
  name = "qq-git"
  url = "https://test.com/"
  id = 38
  token = "QcsLLts6rhLy7Fd7i3JP"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-02-01T21:50:26Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:2.7"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using the tsconfig path mapping.
I added the tsconfig.json file in my root directory, then used the mapping below.
Reference - https://playwright.dev/docs/test-typescript#typescript-with-esm

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",  
      "paths": {
        "@pages/*": ["pages/*"]  
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks, @EnergY for your suggestions regarding the original issue
I hope this helps someone out

Comment: Hi @tedtrain, I'm glad to hear it solved your problem. Regarding the original problem, could you please accept my response if it proved useful? This not only helps others find solutions faster, but also acknowledges the discussion we've had about the **different workarrounds in the comments**. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

there may be two workarounds for your problem.

1. Edit your `config.toml` file by adding and changing this lines :

`config.toml`

```
...
executor = "docker"
shell = "bash" ## <- add this line
[runners.cache] 
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0 
[runners.docker] 
    tls_verify = false 
    image = "ruby:2.7" 
    privileged = true ## <- and this to true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false 
    oom_kill_disable = false 
    disable_cache = false 
    volumes = ["/cache"] 
    shm_size = 0
```

2. If this doesn't work change your image keyword in your pipeline into this by adding the `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` entrypoint  :

> ```
> stages:
>    - test
>
> tests:
>   ...
>   stage: test
>   image: 
>     name: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.41.1-jammy
>     entrypoint: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ] # or entrypoint: [ '/bin/bash', '-c' ]
>   script:
>     - npm ci
>     - npx playwright test
>   ...
> ```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and now I am getting this error 

**sh: 7: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string**

@EnergY

Comment: make sure to respect the tabulation of the toml file, in my answer i just provided the necessary lines to add, you should add them to your original toml file.

here is a pastbin of what it should look like : [https://pastebin.com/raw/03AvRAAm](https://pastebin.com/raw/03AvRAAm)

Comment: I tried both solutions, but neither of them worked.
@EnergY

Comment: hi, i tried to reproduce your problem but didn't get your error message on my `gitlab-runner 16.8.0`, i did notice in the given image that you are still using `gitlab runner v15.0.0` and maybe you should try the newer versions (16.x), and also on your gitlab runner logs you are using the mcr.microsoft.com/playwright image with tag `v1.39.0-jammy` instead of the latest `v1.41.1-jammy`.

Comment: Also if that didn't work, you can try to use the manual method of installing the browser in your CI agent instead of using the `mcr.microsoft.com/playwright` docker image according to the doc : https://playwright.dev/docs/ci#introduction . So in your gitlab pipeline, you can use a `node` image and follow these steps to install the dependencies with CLI : https://playwright.dev/docs/browsers#install-system-dependencies  |  
From the doc :
> "Ensure CI agent can run browsers: Use our Docker image in Linux agents or install your dependencies using the CLI."

Comment: I will update to the newer version. I appreciate your assistance

Comment: Hi @tedrain, I'd like to know if one of the proposed solutions worked for you

Comment: Yes. I just installed a new GitLab instance with the latest runner today
Now I  am running into a new issue. 
The test runs fine on my machine, but when I run it on GitLab I get 
**Error: Cannot find module '../../pages/login/LoginPage'**
What could be the issue?
 
Thanks

@EnergY

Comment: Simply import your module from an absolute path like `src/.../page/login/LoginPage` because sometimes npm can miss module imports if you use a relative path like your case

Comment: How can I use the absolute path? The tests are written on a Windows machine. The absolute path is C:\Users\someUser\Documents\LOCAL REPOSITORY\playwright-portal-test-automation\pages\login\loginPage.ts This will not work on a Linux host where Gilab is installed. Don't I need a way to specify my current working directory regardless of my OS? In Java, I can use System.getProperty("user.dir"). Is there something similar? @EnergY

Comment: Sorry @tedtrain for the confusion, but I meant import from your project's root directory ( like `src/../path/to/module ` ) so in your example `playwright-portal-test-automation\pages\login\loginPage.ts`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not work. This is the error message that I am getting

**Cannot find module 'playwright-portal-test-automation/pages/login/loginPage.ts' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)**

Comment: Hey @tedtrain, could you go back to your import statement when you encountered the **Error: Cannot find module '../../pages/login/LoginPage'** and double-check the path? Remember, paths are case-sensitive. I had a similar issue with an import where I was importing `"../../../redux/services/paymentsAPI"` instead of `"../../../redux/services/paymentsApi"` Checking the casing might help resolve the problem.

Comment: You can also try the "Clear Runner caches" button through the Gitlab UI. [Gitlab Clear the cache manually](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#clear-the-cache-manually)